# Are there any hidden reputation changes?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Just wondering if someone keep kicking my reputation by hundreds just for their entertainment, or it's some automated mechanism. Anyway, I wish these changes were not silent but reflected on the reputation page for my reference. Is it possible?

EDIT:
Thanks to explanations below, I've got the idea. But feature request is still persists: to reflect such a funny penalties on the "Recent Activity" page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see on your [reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top), they **are** visible.

It is not normal, though, more like some people flagged some of your posts as offensive (rightly or not, I can't say, I don't see them). If you think this was abusive, you should report that to the team@stackoverflow.com, normally. However, since you posted it here already, it is probably enough attention already.

Comment: Ahaha, just noticed these stupid community locks :) Thank you!

Comment: @Gnoupi - to be fair, some of his answers are a little on the offensive side (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586314/how-do-you-echo-a-string-with-every-char-in-php/2586324#2586324 for those of you with 10K on SO)

Comment: @Dominic - it's possible, but I can't see that indeed. I will rephrase the answer, though.

Comment: I rephrased an answer as well :) No, I don't think it's abusive or such, actually I don't care of reputation at all. I just wondered at the mechanism.

Comment: @Dominic But the question you pointed to indeed was terrible one. What's wrong with this definition? This community lock looks like more personal attack, not a real community act.

Comment: @Col - it's the way you phrased it that is borderline offensive (putting "your question is terrible" in the answer). If something about a question is unclear so that you can't answer it, leave a comment politely asking what the questioner meant (as webbiedave did). If you have a hunch what they want, then post an answer, perhaps saying that this might not do what they want, and ask them to clarify the question if it doesn't. There's no need to go around calling people's questions terrible.

Comment: @Col: Dominic is wrong! There is a need to go around calling people's questions terrible. We call that **downvote**. It improves the quality of the site. Do it as often as appropriate.

Comment: @Ladybug - totally agree (except for the part about me being wrong!)

Answer (score 5):

As has already been noted, you've tripped a few flag tipping points. I think the best thing to do would be to see how the community is responding to these posts, and try to structure your replies in a less negative way in the future. Your contributions are valued and welcome; the tone less so.

Comment: Too bad, I don't care much of anonymous community opinion.

Comment: especially if it was not a community but a person, who hammered couple archaic answers on purpose ;-)

Comment: @Col.: But it wasn't a "person".  You won't get hit with damages for a single person flagging a question...it has to be flagged by (5? 6?) people before you take the loss.  The point being that you apparently have several answers that are being flagged by multiple people.  (Note: I do not have enough rep on SO to even view these answers, so I can't make any statement about whether I personally might find them offensive or not).

Comment: @Col: to us, *you* are anonymous. Using your logic, why should we care about your opinion either?  Either learn to cooperate with the community (and an anonymous one should be the easiest of all), or please leave.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: As beska said, it takes 6 people for each of those answers. I flagged some of them but not others, so it's not just the same 6 people every time.

Comment: @Ether hehe, I never asked you to care about my opinion :) I don't care about opinions at all. Knowledge I prefer.

Comment: @Col - that may be the case, but please note that the stackoverflow community disagrees with you. Making valid points that somebody is wrong is *fine* and encouraged; but being rude about it is going to lead to problems very quickly. This isn't usenet.

Comment: I love how SO doesn't tolerate rudeness, but I'd also be saddened to see Col. Shrapnel leave. I hope this works out.

Answer (score 4):

You lost 600 points because (I think) at least five people flagged your answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482562/2482836#2482836), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528112/2528150#2528150), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579744/2579807#2579807) and three others (visible to owner and 10k+ only, check the reputation graph stats to find them) as offensive. That makes you lose 100 points each.

I guess you can appeal to moderators about those, but looking at the language you used I doubt whether that is going to change anything :D

Comment: This kind of answer I don't like. Either give or get. Why bother to rephrase earlier answer?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel why not?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I'm confused...you don't like his answer because of "Either give or get."?  I think I'm missing something.